# Type promoting abs implemention

Tags: c++, c++11, std

While `std::abs` (or `::abs` for *C* devs) does not promote the return value and therefor not handle `std::numeric_limit<T>::min()`, I would like to have an `abs` implementation, which does more 'secure' processing.

```
template <typename T>
typename std::make_unsigned<typename std::enable_if<std::is_signed<T>::value, T>::type>::type secure_abs( T value ) {
    if( value >= 0 )
        return value;

    if( value == std::numeric_limits<T>::min() )
        return *reinterpret_cast<typename std::make_unsigned<T>::type*>(&value);

    return -value; //TODO: Prevent promotion to int
}
```

The thing I have not figured out yet, is how to prevent the conversion warning after the promotion to int (when removing the minus).

Is there any more elegant/correct way of removing the minus?

EDIT:

Should now be correct for INT_MIN and 2complement.

Comment: Note that calling this function on INT_MIN is undefined behavior, and recent versions of gcc may even take advantage of that fact to break your code. You need to cast to unsigned before applying operator-, or compute 1-(value+1).

Comment: "whe removing the minus"? I don't understand. Why do you want to remove the minus? The whole function would simply be "return value;" then, won't it? Can you elaborate?

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: he means, when *negating* the number

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf ohh my god. i'm such a fool :)

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: he he, a fool with 191K rep on SO. la la la :-)

Comment: What compiler (with what flags) is giving you what warning for what code exactly? I am not getting any warning here.

Comment: @MarcGlisse Compiler is gcc 4.7 with `-Wextra` and `-Wconversion`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since type promotion to `int` is inevitable when using arithmetic operations with types which "rank" is lower than `int` I see only 2 ways how to overcome this warning:

1. Complex. `return adder(!value, 1);` where `adder` function is a
   bitwise summator. You may find how it is implemented in hardware and
   implement one yourself.
2. Simple. `return static_cast<T>(-value)`. Since you doesn't have any arithmetic operation which may cause overflowing of the type `T` it is absolutely safe to "cancel" promotion to `int`

Comment: For 2. the promotion is still done by minus, right. So the cast might just silence the false positive analysis!?

Comment: Yes, it just silences compiler. If you use any arithmetic operation you have no choice but silence it. Another method is also mentioned, but I don't think it worths the efforts of writing custom adder